Unexpected values in HashSet before method invocation in Java
package main;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class IsBSTTree {

     Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)));
            String[] line = in.readLine().split(" ");
            IsBSTTree solution = new IsBSTTree();
            Node root = solution.buildTree(line, 0, line.length - 1);
            if (solution.isBstTree(root, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
                out.println("Yes");
            } else {
                out.println("No");
            }
            out.flush();
        }

        Boolean isBstTree(Node node, int min, int max) {
            
            if (node == null) 
                return true;

            if (node.data <= min || node.data >= max) 
                return false;
            if (set.contains(node.data)) 
                return false;
            
            set.add(node.data);

            if (isBstTree(node.left, min, node.data) || 
                    isBstTree(node.right, node.data, max)) {
                return false;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public Node buildTree(String[] arr, int from, int to) {
            if (from > to) return null;

            int middle = from + (to - from) / 2;
            Node node = new Node();
            node.data = Integer.valueOf(arr[middle]);
            node.left = buildTree(arr, from, middle - 1);
            node.right = buildTree(arr, middle + 1, to);
            return node;
        }

        class Node {
            int data;
            Node left;
            Node right;
        }
    }


Problem Description

The set variable is supposed to track the node values to detect
duplicates and validate the BST.
However, while debugging, I noticed
that set already contains values before the isBstTree method is
invoked.
I can't understand how values are being added to the set
before the method runs. Expected Behavior The set should be empty
when the isBstTree method starts, and only get populated during the
method's execution.

Actual Behavior
The set contains values before the isBstTree method is called.
Questions

How is it possible for set to contain values before the isBstTree method is invoked?
What changes are necessary to ensure that the set behaves as expected?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Your main reads from standard input. What should we provide as input to reproduce the behaviour you mention? Where should we check the size of set to see that it is not zero? I cannot reproduce what you indicate. I suspect this is not the exact code you have the problem with, but that other code instantiates your class. Please provide your debugging information and make sure it is reproducible.

Actually, this is my input: 1 2 3 4 5, and the set contained 1, 3, 4, which are supposed to be in the set after finishing the isBstTree method. I use Eclipse IDE.
I wanted to check the recursive function, so I debugged this code multiple times. I noticed an issue: the values were added from the input I entered, but I had only just reached the breakpoint in if (solution.isBstTree(root, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE))
Now, I ran a different file with different code and then returned to this code, but it works as expected. I couldn’t reproduce the issue. Do you know why this happened?

This can only happen if you run the method multiple times on the same instance.
